# Are we going the wrong direction in marriage?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Gemara in Yevamos 63a has the following instructions:

> נחית דרגא ונסיב איתתא
>
> Go down a step and marry a woman

At every wedding I've been to, the wedding canopy has been elevated from the ground, such that the groom is going *up* steps to marry a woman!

It seems we have gotten the direction mixed up. Is there some explanation for our practice, which seems to be contradicted by the Talmud?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I disagree with your premise. Many have the minhag thatthe chattan meets the kalla and invites her to the chuppah. Thus, considering that the chattan is already up there, he msut go down to meet the kallah, and then they both rise up to the chuppah. This is what I did at my wedding, and I have seen many others do likewise.

Comment: I was at a wedding [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anshei_Sphard_Beth_El_Emeth_Congregation) where the Chuppah was at the bottom of all those stairs.

Comment: @DanF aside from the fact that generally only sefardim actually go that far out of the chuppah, this is Purim Torah...

Comment: @DoubleAA wow, that's machmir on נחית דרגא

Comment: @Yez Indeed, it was a tremendous inspiration to see how good Erlicha Yidden can be so dedicated to Frumkheit.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is quite simple, actually.

Marriage is called קדושין which comes from the word קדש, meaning "holiness".

There is a common rule in halacha that says, מעלין בקודש ולא מורידין - We go up with holiness, not down.

Thus, in a marriage, the man must go up, not down.